# fixed header within material-ui LeftNav

Tags: css, material-ui

I was trying to create a fixed header (in this case, a Toolbar) within a LeftNav so that when the LeftNav scrolls, the Toolbar stays in its position. But somehow applying `postion: 'fixed'` to the Toolbar doesn't seem to work within LeftNav. When the content within the LeftNav is more than window height, the whole LeftNav, including the top Toolbar with `fixed` position, scrolls. Have anyone figured out how to create a fixed position element within a LeftNav?

Here is the code for reference:

```
...
const toolBarStyle = {
  position: 'fixed',
  top: 0,
};
return (
  <LeftNav
    open={open}
    docked={false}
    onRequestChange={onRequestChange}
  >
    <Toolbar style={toolBarStyle}> />
    {this.props.children} // children could be a lot of content
  </LeftNav>
);
...
```

Comment: try `position: fixed;`

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. I really meant `fixed` not `absolute`. I've corrected it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. All I did was to set the `LeftNav` itself to `position: 'fixed'`, and added a wrapper div around the content and set `overflowY: 'auto'`. Here is the code:

```
......
render() {
const toolBarStyle = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
};
const containerStyle = {
  position: 'fixed',
  top: 0,
  overflowY: 'hidden',
};
const contentContainerStyle = {
  marginTop: 57, // the same height as the toolbar
  width: '100%',
  // you can obtain the window height whatever way you want. 
  // I was using Redux so I pass it down from parent component as a prop
  height: this.props.windowSize.height - 57, 
  overflowY: 'auto',
};
return (
  <LeftNav
    style={containerStyle}
    docked={false}
    onRequestChange={onRequestChange}
  >
    <Toolbar style={toolBarStyle} />
    <div style={contentContainerStyle}>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  </LeftNav>
);
...
```